# Can non-clerics rebuke undead to bolster themselves?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead

Dread Necromancer is a class who can rebuke undead. When they attain 20th level, they become [a lich](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lich.htm).

My players have just encountered one like this. One of the players was a cleric. It was obvious he would try to use turn undead on the lich. I am not sure if I've made a mistake, but I allowed the lich to bolster himself.

I am aware that evil undead clerics can bolster themselves, but I am not sure how it works with other classes with rebuke undead ability. Can they do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem has been solved in the **Rules Compendium**.

> **Bolstering**
>
> [...]
>
> If you can rebuke a target of the same type as you, you can bolster yourself in this way.

Page 147